# SharePoint 2013 designer WF is unable to create task in share point task list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, workflow-tasks-list, app-step

I am trying to execute one task process action in SharePoint 2013 designer WF. It gets stuck at this action and do n't proceed without any error. Even it does not create any task  item in the associated task list.
I have checked below things to investigate the cause but no luck.

1-provided explicit full permission to the task list.
2-Tried adding app step to include that action and provided that Workflow app permission in appinv.aspx.
3-thought the list schema may be corrupted, so created another new list and ran the same WF , no luck.

Please see the screen shot of the simple  workflow and kindly help me out to resolve the same.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please suggest any solution if any one has faced this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to associate your workflow to another task list and see if it works.

Comment: Hello Michael,
Thanks for the response.
I have already checked this by associating the workflow to another new task list. But the same issue.